# Convert unformatted string (not valid json) to json

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have a string which I get from a webservice which looks like this:

```
({
id=1;
name="myName";
position="5";
})
```

which is not a parsable json. I wanted to ask if there are any ways besides going character to character and correcting them to convert such string into a parsable json like this:

```
{
"id":1,
"name":"myName",
"position":"5"
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's not even a valid json ?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh No it's not

Answer (score 0):

Check this link it will be helpful :

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/json-web-services.366073/

Comment: I can parse valid jsons without problem , the problem is it's not a valid json

Answer (score 0):

You cold run a bunch of regex replaces for each change. But you'll need captures for the property names etc The performance will be horrible.

If the format is known and reliable (eg what happens with collections/arrays and sub-objects). And the service provider does not provide a client or SDK. Then your best bet is to write your own parser. It's not that hard to create your own from scratch. Or you can use a parser library like Irony.net or eto.parse. Both of these allow you to construct a grammar in c# so it is fully self contained without the need for compiler-compilers and generated code. There is also a class of parser called "monadic" parsers like Sprache which are of a simpler nature (once you wrap your head around them).

Whichever approach is taken you'll end up with a way of recognising each property and object boundary where you can do what you need to do: set a property; create a JToken; whatever...

Then you can wrap the whole lot in a `MediaTypeFormatter` and call the service via `HttpClient` and get objects out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had to write my own function to convert it to a parsable json, here's the function I wrote:

```
public string convertToJson(string mJson)
{
    mJson = mJson.Replace("(","[");
    mJson = mJson.Replace(")","]");
    string mJson2 = mJson.Trim('[',']');
    string[] modules = mJson2.Split(',');
    for(int i = 0;i<modules.Length;i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("module["+i+"]: " + modules[i]);
    }
    for(int m=0;m<modules.Length;m++)
    {

        char[] mCharacter = {'{','}'};
        modules[m] = modules[m].Replace("{",string.Empty).Replace("}",string.Empty).Trim();
        Debug.Log("module["+m+"] after trim: " + modules[m]);

        string[] items = modules[m].TrimEnd(';').Split(';');
        modules[m] = "{";
        for(int j=0;j<items.Length;j++)
        {
            Debug.Log("item["+j+"]: " + items[j]);
            string[] keyValue = items[j].Split('=');
            Debug.Log("key,value: " + keyValue[0] + ", " + keyValue[1]);
            modules[m] = modules[m] + "\"" + keyValue[0].Trim() + "\":" + keyValue[1].Trim() + ",";
        }
        modules[m] = modules[m].Substring(0,modules[m].Length-1) + "}";
        Debug.Log("modules["+m+"] final: " + modules[m]);
    }
    string finalJson = "[";
    for(int m=0;m<modules.Length;m++)
    {
        finalJson = finalJson + modules[m] + ",";
    }
    finalJson = finalJson.Substring(0,finalJson.Length-1) + "]";
    Debug.Log("finalJson: " + finalJson);
    return finalJson;
}
```